# Can I Connect to a Local SMB Share?

Tags: macos, smb

When attempting to connect to smb://localhost/share, I receive an error that I ought to access the files locally. This is not always desirable. For example, this means I can not use my portable home on my Mac Mini that is serving the home directory.

Windows (via native SMB/CIFS) and other *nix systems (via Samba) can access local shares just fine. Why can I not do so on OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since found that accessing SMB shares from localhost simply isn't supported. However, I have no single authoritative documentation to cite here, but suffice it to say it cannot be done (natively).

More to the point, [it is not supported to log on with a mobile account onto the server hosting the home shares](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3090) - you should only use local accounts.

Comment: Is this still valid in OS X Server 3.1.1 on Mavericks?

Comment: The ifconfig solution above seems to be working under macOS 12.7.2, not sure when it got fixed.

Answer (score 6):

According this this link it is possible:

https://www.chrisnewland.com/solved-mac-osx-samba-cifs-through-ssh-tunnel-error-the-server-localhost-is-available-on-your-computer-364

> Finder identifies smb://127.0.0.1 as a local filesystem and refuses
>   to mount port 445 even if you've set up an SSH tunnel using
>
> ```
> -L 445:localhost:445
> ```
>
> The solution is to alias your lo0 interface to
>      127.0.0.2 and Finder doesn't see this as a local address.
>
> ```
> sudo ifconfig lo0 127.0.0.2 alias up
> ```
>
> Create the ssh tunnel and map to your    Samba / CIFS server
>
> ```
> ssh user@remote -L 127.0.0.2:445:smbhost:445
> ```
>
> Now you can open the share in Finder
>
> ```
> smb://user@127.0.0.2
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you anwser. I used this approach to access a virtualbox ubuntu guest on OSX. For me there has been only two little differences. First I had to create the ssh tunnel as 'sudo' and I opened the smb share with 'smb://127.0.0.2/name_of_share

Comment: Just `sudo ifconfig lo0 127.0.0.2 alias up` is sufficient for testing smb overhead when filesharing on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

Of course is difficult to give an answer without details such as OS X version, type of networking and so on.

Generally though, I experienced that by **restarting File Sharing** (by deselecting/selecting the checkbox from the Sharing Preference Pane) solves several issues, such as Windows machines not being able to connect to Mac shares. This issue was due to a race condition in OS X (that in 10.8.5 seems to be still not resolved) where the smb service starts before an auth service, causing it to fail when other computers try to access shared folders with any sort of privileges.

Are you trying to connect to network shares with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> ? It generally works, otherwise if you click `Browse` you can see all the attached devices an their shares.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding what I'm asking. I was trying to connect to an SMB share on a Mac from the same Mac. I have since found this is not supported (which is a fundamental flaw, but oh well).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch the fact that you were connecting to localhost… I took it as placeholder ;)